# Make gif (ffmpeg) using MOST RECENT 7 jpg files in a directory

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I have a bash script which runs on a cron, to take screenshots of my cctv 1x per day to do an annual timelapse. It all works, and I get a YTD `sofar.gif` of the very first screenshot to the very last screenshot -- which is now quite long. I wanted to add a line to make `last7days.gif` so I could get a shorter weekly gif etc.

I have searched this site and the web and can list the newest 7 files in terminal using: `ls -1t | head -n 9 | tail -n 7` (this removes the .gif and .mov which are modified last) but I do not know how to make that vertical list of 7 filenames into a variable to make a gif using those file names

```
# runs from a cronjob. saves live screenshot from CCTV to jpg, then updates the year-to-date movie

if [ $# -ne 1 ]
then
  echo "Usage: `basename $0` OUTDIR"
  exit 65
fi

doexit=0

start=$(date +%s)
end=$(date +%s)

outdir=${1%/}
mkdir $outdir
echo "Capturing image..."

counter=$(date +"%Y_%m_%d_%H-%M-%S");
file=$outdir/$counter.jpg

if response=$(curl --silent --write-out %{http_code} --max-time 600 'URL REDACTED' -o $file) ; then
    echo "Captured & saved $file!"
else
    echo "Failed to capture $file"
fi

ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel panic -pattern_type glob -i $outdir/'*.jpg' $outdir/sofar.mov -y
ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel panic -pattern_type glob -i $outdir/'*.jpg' $outdir/sofar.gif -y

exit 1
```

Currently, the last lines create a .gif using *every* image file, this works only because they are saved with the date in the filename.

I want to add a line to create a .gif using just the most 7 recent images

Comment: [BashFAQ #3](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003) is pertinent. Though... the filename sorts to put them in the right order? Which version of bash is this? (Is it new enough to allow negative numbers to be used to index from the end of a range?)

Comment: Using `ls` in any context where its output will be read programatically is bad form; see [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 3):

Do the globbing in the shell, then you can take whatever subset you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#              ^^^^- NOT /bin/sh; array support is required.

shopt -s nullglob
files=( "$outdir"/*.jpg )
file_count=${#files[@]}

if (( ${#files[@]} == 0 )); then
  echo "ERROR: No files found" >&2; exit 1;
elif (( ${#files[@]} > 7 )); then
  files=( "${files[@]:$(( ${#files[@]} - 7 ))}" )
fi

input_args=( )
for f in "${files[@]}"; do
  input_args+=( -i "$f" )
done

ffmpeg "${input_args[@]}" "$outdir/sofar.gif"
```

Comment: wow thanks very much, I can see the logic and have read up on a few things; nullglob, files[@]so thanks again for that. But when it runs, it gives an error `"-i: No such file or directory"`. I was trying to figure it out and noticed when I remove the `-i` from the `input_args+=( -i "$f" )` line, i do see the most 7 recent filenames echoed in the terminal by ffmpeg, but the resulting .gif is just the first frame / one frame

Comment: A sample of the file list. the filename matches the modified date exactly. ```2019_07_15_19-30-00.jpg
2019_07_14_19-30-00.jpg
2019_07_13_19-30-00.jpg
2019_07_12_19-30-00.jpg
2019_07_11_19-30-00.jpg
2019_07_10_19-30-00.jpg
2019_07_09_19-30-00.jpg```

Comment: if I echo the `${input_args[@]}` it returns; `Making weekly..
-i 365/2019_07_10_15-00-00.jpg -i 365/2019_07_11_15-00-00.jpg -i 365/2019_07_12_15-00-00.jpg -i 365/2019_07_13_15-00-00.jpg -i 365/2019_07_14_15-00-00.jpg -i 365/2019_07_15_15-00-00.jpg -i 365/2019_07_16_12-00-19.jpg` which seems to break it because it adds the -i over & over and gives the no such file error. Removing -i and adding a comma `,` gives error; `365/2019_07_11_15-00-00.jpg,: No such file or directory`

Comment: The problem was the initial `-i` before `"${input_args[@]}"` was expanded, so you got `-i -i`. BTW, a good place to start is running a script with `bash -x` so it logs each line it's executing.

Comment: Good tip to add -x thanks as explained before I am a PHP guy so I really do appreciate these tips. Is there an edit to get rid of the `-i: No such file or dir` error which I get from the code in your comment, and to make the gif using 7 images to be output?

Comment: See the change I made to the code already, that should fix that error. (You can click on the "edited *n* minutes ago" link to see exactly what changed and when).

Comment: Ah I see that now, @Charles Duffy. Alas, that edit gives me a single frame gif, just the 7th oldest file. I will look at Concatenate again in bash to see if I cant put these 7 files in a text file, then use that with ffmpeg

Comment: A good place to start would be to manually build a working command line, and then ask how to script its creation. `-i frame1 -i frame2 -i frame3` was obviously my attempt at usage, but my area of expertise is bash, not ffmpeg.